# Differentiating class from instance member with same name in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

How do you differentiate an instance member from a class member having the same name in Swift 3? What's usually working before now produces an error in Xcode 8 beta 5:

> "static member 'textColor' cannot be used on instance of type UITag"

```
public class UITag : UILabel {

    static var textColor = UIColor.white

   override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        textColor = UITag.textColor /* error: static member cannot be used on instance of type UITag */
        text      = " not set "
   }
}
```

Comment: remove static and try once

Comment: Note that adding explicit self.textColor = UITag.textColor doesn't help

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: the static is not the same member than the instance one.

Comment: try with `public var textColor = UIColor.white` or `private var textColor = UIColor.white`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange error and we could discuss whether it is a compiler bug that it is actually allowed to shadow a non-static variable with a static variable, however note that it is definitely bad code to have two properties with the same name, one static and one not static, because the last one will shadow the previous one. Probably `defaultTextColor` would be a better name.

A simple workaround is to use:

```
super.textColor = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the only workaround I've found so far is to explicitly cast self as follows:

```
(self as UILabel).textColor  = UITag.textColor
```

Answer (score 0):

`textColor` is a static variable, which cannot be changed. You can only use it's value as `UITag.textColor`.

`super.textColor = UITag.textColor`  This is basically again calling the instance variable of parent class which is similar to `txtColor` in below example

```
public class UITag : UILabel {

    static var textColor = UIColor.white
    var txtColor = UIColor.red

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        super.textColor = UITag.textColor
        txtColor = UITag.textColor
    }
}
```